# How do I lock my camera view when Pause Menu window activated in Unity scene?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, lockscreen

I have a code that manages my Pause Menu window of my scene.
It works well, but similar to the "Audiolistenner.pause=true", I would also like to lock the camera view when the pause window is activated.

How would I adjust this code? Is it the Screen.lockCursor function? If so, how to implement it?

Here is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PauseMenu : MonoBehaviour
{

    [SerializeField] private GameObject pauseMenuUI;

    [SerializeField] private bool isPaused;
    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            isPaused = !isPaused;
        }

        if (isPaused)
        {
            ActivateMenu();
        }

        else
        {
            DeactivateMenu();
        }
    }

    void ActivateMenu()
    {
        Time.timeScale = 0;
        AudioListener.pause = true;
        pauseMenuUI.SetActive(true);
    }

    public void DeactivateMenu()
    {
        Time.timeScale = 1;
        AudioListener.pause = false;
        pauseMenuUI.SetActive(false);
        isPaused = false;

    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So what script does control your Camera view? -> simply disable it? Alternately use a second camera for the pause that is static and switch between them ^^

Answer (score -1):

### When the pause function start:

```
Vector3 lockedCamPosition = camera.transform.position;
Vector3 lockedCamRotation = camera.transform.rotation;
```

### The somewhere in the update function:

```
camera.transform.position =  lockedCamPosition;
camera.transform.rotation = Quarintine.Euler(lockedCamRotation );
```

Comment: That's doesn't secure that the camera doesn't move in case the camera controlling script is run after your `Update` method. It is also quite inefficient to assign the same values to your camera every frame ..